# Error in a drupal site

Tags: drupal-7

I made a website on `drupal 7.3.9` which shows the following error in the home page. 
[image]

When I searched the file it looks as below

[image]

Please suggest the solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your code and images into the question itself, so that potential answerers don't have to click on them and that way you're more likely to get an answer.  Also please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i dont have enough points to do that :/ please help